# How to create side navigation bar in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create side navigation bar in my app. My mainactivity code is:

```
package com.thechamp.ait;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        if(timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Morning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 12 && timeOfDay < 16){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Afternoon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 21){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Evening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 21 && timeOfDay < 24){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Night", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }




        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected( MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case    R.id.nav_about:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AboutCollege()).commit();
                break;

            case    R.id.nav_Earnmoney:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new EarnMoney()).commit();
                break;

            case    R.id.nav_Feedback:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Feedback()).commit();
                break;
            case    R.id.nav_notice:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new NoticeBoard()).commit();
                break;
            case    R.id.nav_study:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new StudyMaterial()).commit();
                break;
            case    R.id.nav_support:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Support()).commit();
                break;
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}}
```

And here activitymain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/background_pic"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@null"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I created an side navigation bar with these codes, but I am not able to open fragment after clicking on specific fragment.  How can I correct my code. I have follow youtube video but it's not working in my case.

Here is my error log:

```
2020-10-14 18:11:26.782 363-363/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-10-14 18:11:26.782 363-363/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-10-14 18:11:39.348 16712-16712/? E/oid.apps.photo: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-10-14 18:11:39.358 16723-16723/? E/android.youtub: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-10-14 18:11:39.427 16723-16723/? E/YouTube: flushBinderConnectionCallbacks is unverified on SDK 30
2020-10-14 18:11:39.437 191-197/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-10-14 18:11:39.439 191-197/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-10-14 18:11:39.447 506-523/? E/JobScheduler.Background: App com.google.android.gms became active but still in NEVER bucket
2020-10-14 18:11:39.518 408-425/? E/installd: Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl1992756199.tmp: No such file or directory
2020-10-14 18:11:39.518 408-425/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1992756199.tmp: No such file or directory
2020-10-14 18:11:39.704 1003-1793/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api
2020-10-14 18:11:39.896 16723-16788/? E/GEL_DELAYED_EVENT_DEBUG: Failed delayed event dispatch, no dispatchers.
2020-10-14 18:11:44.711 1003-1793/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api
2020-10-14 18:11:59.668 506-523/? E/JobScheduler.Background: App com.google.android.gms became active but still in NEVER bucket
2020-10-14 18:11:59.673 10616-15676/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2020-10-14 18:11:59.727 1003-1793/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api
2020-10-14 18:12:09.692 506-523/? E/JobScheduler.Background: App com.google.android.gms became active but still in NEVER bucket
2020-10-14 18:12:09.693 506-523/? E/JobScheduler.Background: App com.google.android.gms became active but still in NEVER bucket
2020-10-14 18:12:12.577 506-650/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.gms, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2020-10-14 18:12:12.577 506-650/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2020-10-14 18:12:12.577 506-650/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.gms, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2020-10-14 18:12:12.826 506-650/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.gms, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2020-10-14 18:12:12.826 506-650/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2020-10-14 18:12:12.826 506-650/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.gms, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2020-10-14 18:12:13.001 506-650/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.gms, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2020-10-14 18:12:13.001 506-650/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
2020-10-14 18:12:13.001 506-650/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.gms, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
```

Comment: Is the onNavigationItemSelected called?

Comment: yes. please check my all coding. And help me to correct my code

Comment: Then you can try to debug the onNavigationItemSelected method and check what happens. Which item are you clicking?

Comment: It looks like the answer to this one was "use valid XML in your app".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not closing your content frame `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!-- this is your content frame - first child of DrawerLayout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/background_pic"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- ends in here -->

    <!-- this is your side bar attached to "start" (layout_gravity param) -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@null"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

    <!-- you may add more side bars with different layout_gravity -->

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: This is not work in my case it makes my app force stop

Comment: show your exception log

Comment: do you mean logcat or error log

Comment: well, error log is in logcat, isn't it...?

Comment: I have add my error log in my question

Comment: this log isn't related to posted code/UI at all... it even doesn't come from your app, its system log...

Comment: I have edited my post now please check

Comment: same as above, this is NOT exception log, not even log from your app...

Comment: then can you please tell me how to get exception log

Comment: from the log cat, set up filter only for your app (in top right corner of logcat window)

Comment: their is no log text in Log cat